# Let f be a holomorphic function on closed unit disk, and $|f(z)|\leq1$ on $|z|=1$, $f(0)={\frac{1}{2}}$. Show that $|f(z)|\leq {\frac{3|z|+1}{2}}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

It's clear that $|f(z)|\leq 1$ on the closed unit disk by maximum modulus principle. And $|f(z)|\leq|z|$ on the boundary of unit disk. But how can we show the inequality at last?

Comment: First of all: what have you tried so far? hint: Schwarz-Pick...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n \ge 1}a_nz^n$ and let $g(z)=\sum_{n \ge 1}a_nz^{n-1}$. We notice that $f(z)-\frac{1}{2}=zg(z)$ and $|f(z)-\frac{1}{2}| \le \frac{3}{2}$ on the unit disc hence $|zg(z)| \le \frac{3}{2}$ But fixing an $r<1$ it follows by maximum modulus that $|g(z)| \le \frac{3}{2r}, |z| \le r$ hence by passing $r \to 1$ we get $|g(z)| \le \frac{3}{2}, |z|<1$ hence $|zg(z)| \le \frac{3|z|}{2}, |z|<1$

this means $|f(z)|=|\frac{1}{2}+zg(z)| \le \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{3|z|}{2}$ so we are done!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can obtain the inequality by applying the Schwarz lemma as follows. Let $g(z) = \dfrac{z-1/2}{1-z/2}$. Then $g$ is an automorphism of the unit disc. Since you know that $f(z)$ maps the unit disc into itself, the composition
$$(g \circ f)(z) = \frac{f(z)-1/2}{1-f(z)/2}$$
is a well-defined holomorphic map from the unit disc to itself. Note that $(g \circ f)(0) = 0$. Applying the Schwarz lemma, we conclude that $|(g \circ f)(z)| \leq |z|$ for all $z$ on the unit disc. Hence,
$$|f(z)-1/2| \leq |z||1-f(z)/2|$$
for all $z$ on the unit disc. By the reverse triangle inequality, $|f(z)-1/2| \geq |f(z)| - 1/2$. On the other hand, by the usual triangle inequality and the fact that $|f(z)| \leq 1$ on the unit disc, $$|z||1-f(z)/2| \leq |z|(1+|f(z)|/2) \leq \frac{3|z|}{2}.$$ Combining everything together yields the desired inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to prove. Consider $g(z)=\frac{2}{3}(f(z)-\frac{1}{2})$.

Check the conditions of Schwarz lemma for $g$.

- It is clear that $g(0)=0$.
- $|f(z)-\frac{1}{2}|\leq |f(z)|+\frac{1}{2}\leq 1+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}$ for $|z|\leq 1$. This implies $|g(z)|\leq 1$ for $|z|\leq 1$.

Hence Schwarz lemma implies $|g(z)|\leq |z|$, and thus
$$\frac{2}{3}\left(|f(z)|-\frac{1}{2}\right)\leq\left|\frac{2}{3}(f(z)-\frac{1}{2})\right|=|g(z)|\leq |z|$$

Rewrite the inequality and the result is clear.